# How to cast a type to a generic interface which has another interface as its generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, interface, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

I am trying to remove excess if-else logic from my code and still
execute appropriate methods based on what the user selects.

I am getting a compiler error in the main method..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    public interface IBaseService<TVM> where TVM : IBaseVM
    {
        TVM Method1();
        void Method2(TVM param);
    }

    public interface IBaseVM
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child1VM : IBaseVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child2VM : IBaseVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child1Service : IBaseService<Child1VM>
    {
        public Child1VM Method1() { return new Child1VM(); }
        public void Method2(Child1VM param)
        {
            return; //body... }
        }
    }

    public class Child2Service : IBaseService<Child2VM>
    {
        public Child2VM Method1() { return new Child2VM(); }
        public void Method2(Child2VM param)
        {
            return; //body... }
        }
    }

    public class Driver
    {
        public static void Main(string[] ars)
        {
            IBaseService<Child1VM> child1Service = new Child1Service(); // why cant this be of IBaseVM type ?
            IBaseService<Child2VM> child2Service = new Child2Service(); // why cant this be of IBaseVM type ?

            IBaseService<IBaseVM>[] services = new IBaseService<IBaseVM>[]
                {
                    child1Service,   // error
                    child2Service    // error
                };
        }
    }

}
```

I want to be able to call child services without having to use if-else / switch case logic.

If all subclasses could be stored in the above array I could simply call the appropriate method of the appropriate subclass (using array-indexing) based on what the user selects.

Comment: this code does not show any of the errors you specified. instead it show several other errors such as: 1. Child1VM props must be public. 2. Method2 must have a return type.

Comment: I'm still getting an error, those are pretty obvious things unrelated to the propblem. Fixed though..

Comment: which error do you get? your code creates at least 6 different errors and none of them relate to your question not even remotely.

Comment: still you haven't fixed what I've told you in my first comment. the Method2 must have a return type. you can't define a constructor in an interface.

Comment: replaced with complete compilable code (sans the errors i want fixed)

Comment: What does `new Child2Service()` return?

Comment: added body for `child2`. Its structure is the same but the service methods do different things and operate on `child2` objects

Answer (score 0):

Casting `Child1Service` to `IBaseService<Child1VM>` is not possible unless `T` in `IBaseService<T>` is defined as a covariant which is done like this: `IBaseService<out T>`

Now it will give you this error:

> CS1961    Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TVM' must be contravariantly valid on 'IBaseService.Method2(TVM)'. 'TVM' is covariant.

So you'll have to change the parameter of the `Method2` from `Child1VM` to `IBaseVM`.

This will work:

```
public interface IBaseService<out TVM> where TVM : IBaseVM
{
    TVM Method1();
    void Method2(IBaseVM param);
}

public interface IBaseVM
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Child1VM : IBaseVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Child1Service : IBaseService<Child1VM>
{
    public Child1VM Method1() { return new Child1VM(); }
    public void Method2(IBaseVM param)
    {
        return; //body... }
    }
}

public class Driver
{
    public static void Main(string[] ars)
    {
        IBaseService<Child1VM> child1Service = new Child1Service();
        IBaseService<IBaseVM>[] services = new IBaseService<IBaseVM>[]
            {
                child1Service,
            };
    }
}
```

Comment: works for Method1(). Can the type parameter on the interface be made both `covariant` and `contravariant` ? That would solve the overall problem.

Comment: @heyNow: It is illogical for a type to be both covariant and contravariant, for two reasons.  First "out" actually means "not used contravariantly" and "in" actually menas "not used covariantly", so "in and out" would mean *invariant*, not *both contravariant and covariant*.

Comment: @heyNow: Second, suppose we have a T that is both covariant and contravariant. Suppose we have `I<Frog>`.  Since it is covariant, this is convertible to `I<Object>`. Since it is contravariant, this is convertible to `I<NewspaperEditor>` Therefore, `I<Frog>` is convertible to `I<NewspaperEditor>` in this scenario; under what possible circumstances does that make sense? In fact, `I<Anything>` is convertible to `I<AnythingElse>`, which means there are no restrictions; if that's what you mean, say `I<Object>`!

Comment: @heyNow: The only time it would make sense to make an interface both covariant and contravariant in T is *if it did not use T at all*, and that's a pretty unlikely scenario; typically you make an interface generic because you have a use for T. So for all these reasons, it is illegal to make a type both covariant and contravariant in the same parameter. Of course it is perfectly legal to make a type covariant in one parameter and contravariant in the other. `Func<A, R>` for example.

Comment: Ok I can sort of understand why. Then that would mean what I'm trying to do in main() is wrong or a better way exists to do so. Could you point me to some resources ? I felt i was just `replacing conditional with polymorphism`

Comment: @heyNow: If you're looking for information about how we designed the covariance/contravariance feature in C# 4, see my MSDN blog for details. I don't understand what you're trying to do well enough to give good advice on how to structure the program, but I encourage you to not try to put too much business logic into the type system.